# How to create a word set/class in Lua pattern matching?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I am trying to create a word-set (class) instead of the char-set (class) in Lua.

**For Example:**

```
local text = "hello world, hi world, hola world"
print(string.find(text, "[^hello] world"))
```

In this example, the program will try to match any part of the string that doesn't start with **h** or **e** or **l** or **o** characters and has a space and **world** next to it. But I want to make a word-set similar to this that can match the entire word and find a part of the string that doesn't start with the word **hello** and has the space and **world** next to it.

**What I've tried:**

```
local text = "hello world, hi world, hola world"
print(string.find(text, "[^h][^e][^l][^l][^o] world"))
```

It didn't work for some reason.

Comment: You won't be able to do it with Lua patterns as they are not regular expressions and do not support lots of basic regex features, e.g. alternation.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read the same in Lua documentation, but I have also heard there's a workaround to achieve this.

Comment: Replace `hello` with some character (for example `@`) and then search for `any_word+space+world`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, that hello world was just an example. In my project that hello is a variable.

Comment: Replace all non-matching words with `@` prior to searching for a pattern.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I am trying to create a word-set (class) instead of the char-set (class) in Lua.

This is not possible in the general case. Lua patterns operate at a character level: Quantifiers can only be applied to characters or character sets (and some special pattern items), but there exists no alternation, no "subexpressions" etc. Patterns don't have the expressive power required for this.

```lua
local text = "hello world, hi world, hola world"
print(string.find(text, "[^h][^e][^l][^l][^o] world"))
```

what this pattern translates to is: "find  `world` preceded by a space and 5 characters where each character may not be the respective character of hello world. This means all of the following won't match:

- `hi world`: Only three characters before `world`
- `hxxxx world`: First character is the same as the first character of `hello`
- `... hola world`: The `l` from `hola` is at the same position as the second `l` from `hello`

To find `world` *not* preceded by `hello`  I would combine multiple calls to `string.find` to search through the string, always looking for a preceding `hello` :

```lua
-- str: Subject string to search
-- needle: String to search for
-- disallowed_prefix: String that may not immediately precede the needle
-- plain: Disable pattern matching
-- init: Start at a certain position
local function string_find_prefix(str, needle, disallowed_prefix, plain, init)
    local needle_start, needle_end = str:find(needle, init or 1, plain)
    if not needle_start then return end -- needle not found
    local _, prefix_end = str:find(disallowed_prefix, init or 1, plain)
    -- needle may not be prefixed with the disallowed prefix
    if (not prefix_end) or needle_start > prefix_end + 1 then
        -- prefix not found or needle starts after prefix, return match
        return needle_start, needle_end
    end
    return string_find_prefix(str, needle, disallowed_prefix, plain, prefix_end + 2)
end
print(string_find_prefix("hello world, hi world, hola world", "world", "hello ")) -- 17 21: Inclusive indices of the `world` after `hi`
```

See [`string.find (s, pattern [, init [, plain]])`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.find).